# Configure and verify Vnet in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have created a Virtual Network next to its subnet and integrated it into three service applications and created the rule on the firewall of my SQL Azure server.

Everything is in the same Azure subscription and region

I need to know if it is enough to direct all the traffic between these instances through the virtual network or do I need to configure some other aspect.

And how can I query the data traffic to verify that the virtual network is being used?

Comment: Could you please give a bit more details, what Azure resource you are using, how you connected them, what is the architecture?

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for commenting on my post.
I am using a subscription with:
1 Resource Group
1 App Service
2 App Service
1 DB

1 Resource Group
1 App Service
1 DB
1 Vnet

Everything is in the same region of Az.

I want all traffic between resources to be through the Vnet. And also, monitor the traffic to verify the correct operation of the Vnet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Virtual Network (VNets) allows to place Azure resources in a non-internet-routable network.
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/private-web-app/private-web-app#architecture

Using Azure App Service regional VNet Integration, the web app connects to Azure through an AppSvcSubnet delegated subnet in an Azure Virtual Network.

Virtual Network only routes traffic and is otherwise empty, but other subnets and workloads could also run in the Virtual Network.

The App Service and Private Link subnets could be in separate peered Virtual Networks, for example as part of a hub-and-spoke network configuration. For regional VNet Integration, the peered Virtual Networks must be located in the same Azure region.

Azure Private Link sets up a private endpoint for the Azure SQL database in the PrivateLinkSubnet of the Virtual Network.

The web app connects to the SQL Database private endpoint through the PrivateLinkSubnet of the Virtual Network.

The database firewall allows only traffic coming from the PrivateLinkSubnet to connect, making the database inaccessible from the public internet.

Comment: Why don´t I see correctly the net in Monitor Az?? I have the same scheme configured but I can't get all of this to work. How I can verify me net and scheme function correctly?

Comment: Could you please be more specific, what error do you have, what services do not work?